# Regex to find all lines starting with same number which has a specific string in this region

Tags: regex

I want to find all "word-to-find" lines and don't only give me this line as result but all lines near that result which has the same number at line beginning.

So in the example text below this regex should find all lines starting with 777700 and 999900.

```
    ...
 777700  K    Name1*Surname          Street 1                         12345 Town
 777700                                       Here is sentence number 1
 777700                                       Here is sentence number 2
 777700                                       Here is sentence which has word-to-find in it
 777700                                       Here is sentence number 4
 888800  K    Name2*Surname          Street 2                         12345 Town
 888800                                       Here is sentence number 1
 888800                                       Here is sentence number 2
 999900  K    Name3*Surname          Street 3                         12345 Town
 999900                                       Here is sentence number 1
 999900                                       Here is sentence number 2
 999900                                       Here is sentence which has word-to-find in it
```

Comment: What is your question? Which part of the problem are you having trouble solving?

Comment: What language / tools are you using?

Comment: I mean I get the "word-to-find" line with for example `^.+word-to-find.+$`. But I need the lines before (and/or after) this line also when they begin with the same number.

@Aaron Using Sublime Text editor for hihglighting/copy the results....

Comment: Maybe an expression like `(777700|999900).*(?:\1)[^\n]*` with `gs` modifiers.

Comment: @MoisheLipsker I don't know this starting number(s)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oooh, this is trickier than I thought at first. Here's my solution:

```
^(\d+)\b(?=(?:(?!^(?!\1\b)).)*word-to-find)(?:(?!^(?!\1\b)).)*
```

using the `gms` modifiers for the regex flavor you're using (global match, dot matches all, `^` matches line beginnings). In Sublime (which I don't know), you should probably add `(?sm)` at the very start of the regex to make this work.

Please test it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iK5oH8/2) with some more cases.

**Explanation:**

```
^               # Start of line
(\d+)           # Match and capture a number (group 1)
\b              # Make sure we match the entire number
(?=             # Now assert that the following can be matched from here on out:
 (?:            # Start of non-capturing group:
  (?!           # Allow a match only if it's impossible to match...
   ^(?!\1\b)    # ...the start of a line followed by a different number than \1
  )             # End of negative lookahead
  .             # Then match any character
 )*             # any number of times
 word-to-find   # and our search string.
)               # End of positive lookahead
(?:             # Now that we know our search string is there, let's do the actual match:
 (?!^(?!\1)\b)  # which extends until a line follows that starts with a different number
 .              # Match any character
)*              # any number of times
```

Comment: This looking good!!! One detail.. there could be some whitespaces before the numbers at beginning of the line.

@Tamas Rev Program I use to highlight the result is "Sublime Text" Editor.

Comment: @Heart1010: Would that whitespace be consistent across all the lines of the same block? If that's the case, just add `[ \t]*` to the capturing group before `\d+`. If not, add it directly after each single `^` in the regex.

Comment: Perfect! Made Version 3 on your regex101 link which works perfectly with the whitespaces at the line beginnings.

For Sublime Text it's like you mentioned with (?sm) before the regex:

`(?sm)^([ \t]*\d+)\b(?=(?:(?!^(?!\1\b)).)*word-to-find)(?:(?!^(?!\1\b)).)*`

Comment: @TimPietzcker, very cool! (+1). Nevertheless, In this kind of situations I prefer a indirect solution: please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation I prefer to:

- add a explicit record separator `§` (substitute `^(\d+).*(\n\1.*)*`  by `§$0`)
- do the processing I need  (example: find `^[^§]*word-to-find[^§]*`)
- remove the separator

(Untested: spaces, word-boundaries may need some extra work)